# Java AclAttributeView returns multiple AclEntry objects for a single ACL on Windows

Tags: java, windows, acl

I'm working with the Java 1.7 AclAttributeView class to get ACL's for files.

What I'm seeing is that for some files, the Java API call to getAcl() (or perhaps this is Windows' doing) is returning multiple AclEntry objects for a single ACL, where-in the first entry will have permissions, but no flags, and the second entry will have no permissions, but flags.

The behavior this is leading to is that when I write the file back out with the above ACL, I get two ACL's... the first grants full permissions to the parent directory, and the second grants no permissions to all children of said directory. Thus, as the SYSTEM user for example, I can never write anything more than 2 levels deep.

Some test output (ignore the BANANA bits, I use it as debug logging when bored):

```
BANANA :: getMetadata; file=C:\
BANANA :: fromAclEntry()... acl:
BANANA ::         user=BUILTIN\Administrators
BANANA ::         perm=[WRITE_ACL,DELETE_CHILD,APPEND_DATA,WRITE_DATA,WRITE_NAMED_ATTRS,READ_ACL,READ_ATTRIBUTES,WRITE_ATTRIBUTES,EXECUTE,DELETE, ... 4 more]
BANANA ::         flag=[]
BANANA ::         type=ALLOW
BANANA :: fromAclEntry()... acl:
BANANA ::         user=BUILTIN\Administrators
BANANA ::         perm=[]
BANANA ::         flag=[INHERIT_ONLY,FILE_INHERIT,DIRECTORY_INHERIT]
BANANA ::         type=ALLOW
BANANA :: fromAclEntry()... acl:
BANANA ::         user=NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
BANANA ::         perm=[WRITE_ACL,DELETE_CHILD,APPEND_DATA,WRITE_DATA,WRITE_NAMED_ATTRS,READ_ACL,READ_ATTRIBUTES,WRITE_ATTRIBUTES,EXECUTE,DELETE, ... 4 more]
BANANA ::         flag=[]
BANANA ::         type=ALLOW
BANANA :: fromAclEntry()... acl:
BANANA ::         user=NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
BANANA ::         perm=[]
BANANA ::         flag=[INHERIT_ONLY,FILE_INHERIT,DIRECTORY_INHERIT]
BANANA ::         type=ALLOW
BANANA :: fromAclEntry()... acl:
BANANA ::         user=BUILTIN\Users
BANANA ::         perm=[READ_ATTRIBUTES,EXECUTE,SYNCHRONIZE,READ_DATA,READ_ACL,READ_NAMED_ATTRS]
BANANA ::         flag=[FILE_INHERIT,DIRECTORY_INHERIT]
BANANA ::         type=ALLOW
BANANA :: fromAclEntry()... acl:
BANANA ::         user=NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
BANANA ::         perm=[DELETE]
BANANA ::         flag=[INHERIT_ONLY,FILE_INHERIT,DIRECTORY_INHERIT]
BANANA ::         type=ALLOW
BANANA :: fromAclEntry()... acl:
BANANA ::         user=NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
BANANA ::         perm=[APPEND_DATA]
BANANA ::         flag=[]
BANANA ::         type=ALLOW
```

I'm seeing this behavior on Windows 7, 8, and 10, all architectures.

In my contrived example above, I'm able to create a folder structure that looks like:

..\dir1\subdir1

As the SYSTEM user, dir1 gets created with full permissions for SYSTEM to dir1 only, and no permissions are propagated to any children files/folders. subdir1 then has no permissions for the SYSTEM user (there is not even an AclEntry, according to Windows).

Has anybody else seen this / is able to explain what's going on here?

(Note: I see similar "multiple AclEntry" behavior on files/folders other than C:\, as seen in my example)

EDIT small code sample producing similar results...

```
final AclFileAttributeView aclView = Files.getFileAttributeView(file.toPath(), AclFileAttributeView.class);
List<AclEntry> acls = aclView.getAcl();
for (AclEntry acl : acls) {
    System.out.println("user=" + acl.principal().getName());
    System.out.println("perm=" + acl.permissions());
    System.out.println("flag=" + acl.flags());
    System.out.println("type=" + acl.type().name());
}
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of the code you're testing?

Comment: Added a small code sample.